# What's the (dis)adantage of using ViewBag to counter the issues with lazy loading?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

*Please note that **I'm not** having problems with the disposed database context and the question **is not** about how to handle the not-yet-loaded navigational properties.*

I've seen two different suggestions on how to handle the exception below.

> The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22007332/1525840), which I've always used recommends *Include(item => item.property)*. However, there's [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32491433/1525840) and it suggest using *ViewBag*, which I've never seen before in this context.

My question is whether there are any advantages to using *ViewBag* or if the *Include* approach is a generally the best?

Comment: `ViewBag` is a local storage (simple dictionary variable) in ASP.NET MVC it's not related to EF

Comment: Am I to understand that the second suggestion is just a confused speculation and not the actual answer? I've never used it and I don't feel like wasting time testing it, unless there's a wise reason to.  :)

Comment: What you linked to isn't a solution or recommendation - it's a bad answer. It won't work unless everything is eagerly loaded. There's no difference between storing the data in a ViewBag or any other variable or property

Comment: I guess that answer sneaked past the review process because it was added months after the question was asked and it kinda looks like a good answer if you don't know the domain at all. Other than that, it's nonsense and should be removed.

Comment: @DavidG there are other, dangerous answers to that question. The linked answer is just wrong. The one about not disposing the context though, is dangerous

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed, I'm just looking at them now...